# Gaussian noise added in social sciences data

Tags: r, regression, normal-distribution, simulation, noise

In a simulation study (number of simulation $n=200$), there is this quadratic/parabolic function simulated with Gaussian noise added:

```r
y= 4 * (x - 0.5)^2 + rnorm(200, 0, 0.05)
```

With $x$ as a variable which follows a uniform distribution ranging from $0$ to $1$. My question concerns the Gaussian noise added `rnorm(200,0,0.05)` with therefore the following inputs:

- $n=200$
- $\text{mean}=0$
- $\text{SD} = 0.05$

As a reminder, the standard normal distribution (often called the bell curve) has mean = $0$ and a standard deviation = $1$.

Is this type of Gaussian noise with mean = $0$ and standard deviation = $0.05$ (much lower than $1$) likely to be present in social science data? Or would we need a different Gaussian noise of the type `rnorm(200,2,3)` with mean at $2$ and standard deviation at $3$? Or any other means and any other standard deviations for Gaussian noise (for example mean at $5$ or $8$ or $12$,... and standard deviation at $3, 5, 7,$...)?

Or do the values ​​of means and standard deviations not have much importance in the Gaussian noise used in social sciences data simulations?

Answer (score 0):

For your two major questions:

> Or do the values ​​of means and standard deviations not have much importance in the Gaussian noise used in social sciences data simulations?

They should obviously matter in *any* context.

> Is this type of Gaussian noise with mean = $0$ and standard deviation = $0.05$ (much lower than $1$) likely to be present in social science data? Or would we need a different Gaussian noise of the type `rnorm(200,2,3)` with mean at $2$ and standard deviation at $3$? Or any other means and any other standard deviations for Gaussian noise (for example mean at $5$ or $8$ or $12$,... and standard deviation at $3, 5, 7$,...)?

This is going to entirely field-dependent (psychology is a very broad science), context-dependent (because there are many types of questions even in those fields), and question-dependent (e.g. the complexity of your analysis). Some psychological data is going to be *very* noisy while some will be comparatively precise. That's just the nature of the variety of information out there, so past research will be your best guide.

Whatever you are trying to simulate, try to see if there are previous papers on this topic which report the residual standard error (RSE) and try to approximate that as best you can. This will guide selection of your `rnorm` function arguments. On a side note:

> As a reminder, the standard normal distribution (often called the bell curve) has mean = 0
> and a standard deviation = 1

This is just a assumption used for mathematical convenience. When considering an actual population or sample mean/SD, these can vary considerably. For example, the original IQ scores had an estimated normal distribution with mean = $100$ and a standard deviation of $15$.